# Are there any advantages of Vulkan using traditional methods?

Tags: opengl, vulkan

I keep hearing that Vulkan meant for direct low level operations with the GPU and hence it's targeted toward expert and experienced graphics programmers.

What would be some other advantages of Vulkan that are usable for a more traditional graphics programmer, rather than a full blown AAA expert?

One advantage I keep hearing about is multi-threading support. It's buzzing in media to annoying levels, yet still never explained what and how it's different from OpenGL's level of multi-threading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Vulkan and how does it differ from OpenGL?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96014/what-is-vulkan-and-how-does-it-differ-from-opengl)

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou Not a duplicate at all, I'm asking about difference in a very specific scope rather than a list of general difference, so please stop marking this for no reason

Comment: I agree with the duplicate vote. It sounds like the same question. Which part is this "very specific scope" you mentioned?

Comment: "What would be some other advantages of Vulkan that are usable for a more traditional graphics programmer, rather than a full blown AAA expert?"

That part , It doesn't even mentions openGL , although in the later part openGL is mentioned as a comparison, but it could be replaced with Direct X as well

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, then it's too broad.